# 5.0.9 error on Exchange code for access token

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

I've followed "Getting Started with an ASP.NET MVC 3 Website" and it has worked fine (5.0.8) until I updated the SDK to 5.0.9.

I've got this error when trying to exchange code for access token:

```
Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: a. Line 1, position 1.
```

It occurs at

```
dynamic tokenResult = oAuthClient.ExchangeCodeForAccessToken(code);
```

The "code" is correct as it used to be.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, I solved it downloading the source code from CodePlex and compiling again the Facebook.dll. With the one that I downloaded from NuGet I had the same problem that you are having now.

Comment: excellent - for those looking for the codeplex version download it from here: http://facebooktoolkit.codeplex.com